# Angular Table - Columns are not totaling/summing up for a calculated column. Totals works fine only when value in inputted in the input textbox

Tags: angular, calculated-columns

**html code**

```
<table>
     <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Items</th>
          <th>Value</th>
          <th>% of value</th>
          <th>Rate</th>
          <th>Calculated Value</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
      <tbody formArrayName="Details">
        <tr *ngFor="let item of Details.controls;">
          <td>
            <input class="width-15" matInput type="text" formControlName="ItemName" autocomplete="off">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input matInput type="text" mask="comma_separator.2" prefix="$" autocomplete="off" formControlName="Value">
          </td>
          <td>
            {{percentOfValue(item, Details.controls)}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <input matInput type="text" mask="comma_separator.2" suffix="%" autocomplete="off" formControlName="Rate">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input matInput type="text" mask="comma_separator" prefix="$" autocomplete="off"
                   formControlName="CalculatedValue" value="{{calculatedvalue(item)}}">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td>Totals</td>
          <td>
            ${{ sumColumnTotal('Value') }}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{ sumPercentColumnTotal('percentOfValue') }}  ------------- How to calculate the sum of this column???
          </td>
          <td>
            // No need of totals for rates.
          </td>
          <td>
            ${{ sumColumnTotal('Value') }}
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
</table>

**.ts code**

CalculatedValue(item): string {
    return ((item.value.Value) * (item.value.Rate));
 }
```

// (item value / Sum of all rows)*100 - Dynamic column. When value changes in 2nd column the 3rd column values will be updated automatically.
percentOfValue(item, allItems): string {

```
    const totalValue = allItems.map(c => c.value.Value)
      .reduce((sum, current) => {
        const value = current != null ? current : 0;
        return +this.tryCleanNumber(sum) + +this.tryCleanNumber(value);
      }, 0);
    if (totalValue === 0) {
      return '0%';
    }
    const percent = +this.tryCleanNumber(item.value.Value) / totalValue;

    // * 100 for percent, *100 again and /100 for rounding
    const rounded = (percent * 100 );
    return rounded + '%';
  }
```

Result table in the UI

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yo8HI.png)

Issues with red highligted fields:

1. Calculated Value column total works as expected when we input values in the text box (last column). But Inputting some values in Value (2nd column), would auto populate/calculate the last column value (calculatedvalue). In other words, totals are not working on a "calculated column" but works well when the column in inputted.
2. Advise how to calculate the totals of 3rd column (% of value). Couldn't write any function in ts as the column itself is a calculated column.

Comment: Firstly dont use function. User custom pipe for total calculations. It is not good for percentage

Comment: Can you please create a stackblitz for the problem. it will be easy to find the solution.